# Does it make sense to buy usb 3.0 sd card readers?

Tags: sd

I recently bought a USB 3.0 microSD card reader for a couple of dollars of eBay but haven't quite tested it out. It works only on smaller cards (up to 4GB) which is bad, but not the question.
My question is:

If the circuitry in an SD card reader acts as a serial to serial converter (I'm guessing SDIO or SPI to USB), does the USB interface make a difference in speed?
Does it make sense to buy a USB 3.0 card reader, or will it result in same speeds due to other circuitry limitations?

I will try it out, however, I am interested in a theoretical answer.

Comment: Not all SDcards and readers are created equal. Some claim to be USB 3.0 or a certain speed but there's no guarantee until you see the actual performance in a test. So if using USB 3.0 makes sense depends on the actual implementation. If implemented properly and with an SDcard with sufficient speed, of course it can make a difference. But I do not expect a cheap reader from ebay to benefit from USB 3.0, it would surprise me if it can outperform a more expensive and better designed USB 2.0 reader from a respected brand.

Answer (score 1):

I have two external USB 3 hubs, each connected by a USB 3 cable to the USB 3 socket in different PCs. The hubs are different makes, though could contain the same chip manufacturer's hub IC.

If I plug a USB 3 flash stick into the USB 3 hub, I can write to it at USB 3 speeds nicely.

If I plug a USB 2 flash stick or USB 2 memory card adaptor into the USB 3 hub, the speed of writing to my still-plugged-in USB 3 flash stick drops to USB 2 speeds. So the hub appears to drop to the speed of the slowest device.

I can see the USB-protocol reasons why this happens but it isn't how USB 2 FS (12 Mbps) devices and HS (480 Mbps) devices coexisted.

So, for me, there is a good case for only using USB 3 devices for these PCs, saves the unplugging and replugging, so long as the cost allows.

Incidentally, although it might appear as a serial to serial converter from the ends of its cables, it's taking a block of data from USB, buffering-and-checking it, then sending that block of data to the target flash card. As I imagine you already knew, communicating over USB bus is a separate activity to communicating with the target card.

Answer (score 0):

The fastest SD card right now has 90 Mega Bytes per second read and 65 Mega Bytes per second write speed. Usb 2.0 is 60 Mega Bytes per second maximum theoretical speed. Usb 3.0 is 5 gbps. So theoretically, yes, if you have the fastest newest most expensive sd card out there.

Comment: You might want to notice that you only get like 35 MB/s max speed with USB 2.0 under usual circumstances. You can hit that limit much faster than the 60 MB/s theoretical speed.